# router-view v-bind="$attrs" does not propagate events

Tags: vue-router4

I found that in Vue3 i cannot propagate event from subcomponentes via router-view somehow.

> <router-view v-slot="{Component}" v-bind="$attrs" ...

does not work but

> <router-view v-slot="{Component}" @upload="$event=> $emit('upload',
> $event)"
> does.

Does anybody know if that is intended? Seemd weird compared to Vue2 and also how it's handled in all other components.

Using

```
"vue": "^3.2.47", 
"vue-router": "^4.1.6",
```

Cheers
Tom

Comment: "Does not work" is not a technical description of a problem.

Comment: Decided to go explicit at every forward with @myevent=$event=>$emit('myevent', $event) as also I foudn v-bind="$attrs" seems to go from child->parent but also from parent->child e.g in once case where I had set id as parameter which lead to strange results.